# accessing json data array to store in mongodb, sub documenting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
name:{
    type:String,
    validate: {
        validator: (name) => name.length>2,
        message:'Name must be longer than 2 characters'
    },

},
postCount:{
    type:Number,
    default:0
},
posts:
    type:[PostSchema],
```

});

PostSchema

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
title:{
    type:String,
    required:true
}
```

});

Post method to insert data into user document(mongodb)

```
app.post('/user',(req,res)=>{

console.log(req.body.posts);
var user = new User({
   name:req.body.name,
   posts: req.body.posts
});
user.save().then((doc)=>{
    res.status(200).send(doc);
},(e)=>{
    res.status(400).send(e);
});
```

});

Creating POST request using this JSON Data

```
{
"name":"TIM",
"posts":[
    {"title":"abc", "name":"xxx"},
    {"title":"xyz", "name":"xxx"}]
```

}

After requesting POST method on above JSON data

```
{
"postCount": 0,
"_id": "5c32301725d0c965bd5fa82e",
"name": "TIM",
"posts": [
    {
        "_id": "5c32301725d0c965bd5fa830"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c32301725d0c965bd5fa82f"
    }
],
"__v": 0
```

}

I have created a userschema and sub-documented posts, now i am trying to insert data from postman using post method, but the title is not updating and only the id is generating for an indivisual posts. please help.

I should be able to add name of the user along side the array of posts and their titles.

Answer (score 0):

Try

posts: [PostSchema]

Reference
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Also your post schema doesnt contain name field.
You are trying to insert a name via post.